# Wiring confusion with 3-way switches that control 2 lights

Tags: switch, light

I have no issue troubleshooting 3-way switches but this is an odd one. At some point a handyman replaced switches and messed up a 3-way switch setup. However it's 2 lights and 2 switches:
- light A and switch A at top of stairs
- light B and switch B at bottom of stairs
I want both switches to control both lights simultaneously. However, the way it is now:
- switch A controls both lights fine
- switch B only turns on/off light A, has no effect on light B

Switch A has 3 regular leads: red end which is connected to one traveller terminal, white end which is connected to the other traveller terminal, black wire connected to the black screw but then continues to another switch for an outside light so this appears to be the hot. Then there is an additional end of another black wire. This extra black wire controls light B and seems to be the key to the problem. If I touch it to the hot wire, then light B turns on as expected, if I attach it to either traveller screw, then light B turns on and off with switch A. I'm just not sure what I can do to make light B also turn on and off with switch B.

I've most combinations and nothing seems to get both lights working with both switches. Maybe I'm missing a white wire to light B in the mix somehow?

Thanks for any troubleshooting tips you may be able to provide.

Comment: Can you provide pictures of each switch box and verify the hot feed?

Comment: Because you can't do that with the number of wires available in most 3-way circuits.  Now if the last guy used a /4 cable, then yes; however random "last guys" almost never use /4 cable.   Your concept of powering lamp B from switch B is utterly bankrup--- *hold on. This just in.* Smart switches are now on the market, and may open up this option!

Comment: Also stop "trying combinations". There are many combinations which will work *and will kill you*.  If you don't know why you're doing something with electrical, stop and learn.  Only act with knowledge.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I knew "trying combinations" would get ya...

Comment: Thanks but 120v is not going to kill me. I'm wearing gloves and worst case it will trip the breaker. If the two lights are on the same circuit or both are connected to the same box then there's no reason why the 2 switches can't control 2 lights. Thanks Jack I'll confirm the hot and take the other switch out of box A, that may help clarify how many circuits/wires are going into/through the box.

Comment: How do you know it was a "handyman" and how do you know he didn't intend for it to work this way?

Comment: Steve,  at the very least,  kill the breaker before each time you start swapping connections. Even if you do remember insulating gloves, sparks & melted plastic can be nasty.  I strongly recommend "buzzing out" the connections  with breaker off.  Use an ohmmeter and a length of test wire to reach distant connection points.

Comment: I'm not talking about while you're working on it,  I'm talking after. And yes, 120v can and will kill you, I and it don't care how many times you've been lucky in the past.   If you are cavalier you should stop.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, once I had both switches out of the box and pulled out all the bundled wires it was easy enough to figure out where everything was going and what was going on based on what was working, there was a hot circuit coming in, circuits going out to each light, and the 3-way circuit going between the switches, so it was easy enough to identify the lines running to each light and put them in parallel. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for reporting your results. We're glad to hear both that your lights are working, and that you're still alive.

Comment: Good, sounds like the person who wired it, wired it properly... with both lamps from the same switch box. That was not what was described in the question, hence my concern. Glad it worked out for you!